# How put two glyphs to mp image and get kerning

Tags: fonts, metapost

Is possible to put two glyphs in any place in MetaPost and get kerning between it?

for example using [Lato-Regular.ttf](http://www.latofonts.com/)

> 'ab' in 1.7cm,2cm and get information kerning 'a' and 'b'

or

> put 'a' in (1.7cm,2cm) and 'b' on right kerning +11pt.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Could you please post a complete Minimal Working Example and explain what result exactly you expect? Do you want the information displayed in the console output?

Comment: I dontknowwhat. What put 2 glyph from exactly ttf font? How get information?

Comment: How are you getting access to TTF fonts? Are you using MP through `luamplib`?  Plain Metapost can only use fonts defined via the `psfonts.map` mechanism, which normally does not include any of your system fonts.

Comment: What is the underlying requirement here?  Why do you need the kerning information?

Answer (score 2):

If you create a textual picture like this:

```
   picture pp; pp = "proof" infont "pplri8r";
```

it will be created with the origin of the text sitting at coordinates (0, 0); then you can get the dimensions like this

```
   wd = xpart urcorner pp;
   ht = ypart urcorner pp;
   dp = ypart lrcorner pp;
```

You could use this idea to measure individual characters, but the only way I can think of to get the kerning information would be to measure the widths of `"a"` and `"b"` separately, and then compare them to the width of `"ab"`.

But you can only use `infont` with font names in `psfonts.map`, so you need to get familiar with what Lato is called there.  On my system I see `"Lato-Reg-01"` and so on, but the encodings are strange, so that the standard printable ASCII characters are not in their usual places.

Comment: is possible 'get kerning' from lualatex?    Is posible to put my chars other place than(0,0)?

Comment: Why do you need the kerning information?  It might be easier to use some utility to read it directly from the font?

Comment: > "Is possible to put my chars other place than(0,0)?"  Of course.  It's just easier to measure them if you create the picture without shifting it first.  Once you have a picture variable you can place it anywhere you like with `draw pp shifted (x,y);`  You can `draw` it several times in different places if you want.

Comment: please show me how i can read information about kerning glyph .  script or, command line or perl,python,ruby,C  2) My qestion is HOW pt shifted, where i must write text, can You modyfy answer to put (x,y)?

Comment: @MarekKaski you don't **need** the kerning information to make a properly typeset label - that's all done automatically for you. I'm afraid I don't understand your question.  I'll wait a couple of days and then delete this answer.

Comment: Your answer is good. but i need (more ;-) ) information about kerning for my own script in lua. If you wold like delete question

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the question to explain what you are trying to do?  It's probably not a good idea to do kerning in your own script.  It's almost certainly better to build up a string and then typeset it all at once using the `textext()` macro or the `infont` operator.